# Multiple onclick events - Text Output

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code with onclick events for changing button color and stopping button from being clicked twice.  I also want to add that when a button is clicked it added text/data to a table column/row.  Click button 3, id data from button 3 outputs to a column/row.  Click button 1 next and the id data added to same row/column just adding it to top of list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="Https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".button").click(function () {
        $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .button {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      /* White */
      border: 2px solid #f44336;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 80px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer
    }

    .disabled {
      background-color: #0000ff;
      /* Blue */
      color: white;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    .button-clicked {
      background-color: #FFFF00;
      /* Yellow */
    }

    .buttonreset {
      background-color: #FF0000;
      /* Red */
      border: 4px solid #f44336;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 20%;
      width: 180px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer
    }

    td:not(:first-child) {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><button class="button" id="B1" onclick="myFunction(); 
this.disabled = true">1</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button class="button" id="B2" onclick="myFunction(); this.disabled = true">2</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button class="button" id="B3" onclick="myFunction(); this.disabled = true">3</button></td>
      <td>PUT ID DATA HERE IN ORDER OF BUTTON PRESSED
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table><br><br><br><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far?

Comment: as @TomO. said, could you provide code, what you have tried already and what kind of problem you have?

Comment: Added code, thanks for helping in advance

Comment: not sure why you're defining multiple click events. You should be able to do everything from within one event handler. Also where is "myFunction" and what does it do? You missed that bit out. Lastly, what problem are you facing? You've described what you want to happen, but you haven't told us what difficulty you are having.

Comment: @ADyson sorry I am new to javascripting.  When you say one event handler you are saying I can put it all in the top script portion?

Comment: yes, why not? One function can do lots of jobs. Or it can just be a central place from which to call other functions to do those jobs. What you very rarely need to do is define the same event multiple times on the same element, as you are doing currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? You already have a click function, you just  need to `.append()` a new row to the table with the id. Something like `$("tr").append("<td>" + $(this).attr('id') + "</td>");`

Also remove the `onclick="myFunction(); this.disabled = true"` from your HTML as it throws an error.

Working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="Https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".button").click(function () {
        $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
        $("tr").append("<td>" + $(this).attr('id') + "</td>");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .button {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      /* White */
      border: 2px solid #f44336;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 80px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer
    }

    .disabled {
      background-color: #0000ff;
      /* Blue */
      color: white;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    .button-clicked {
      background-color: #FFFF00;
      /* Yellow */
    }

    .buttonreset {
      background-color: #FF0000;
      /* Red */
      border: 4px solid #f44336;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 20%;
      width: 180px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer
    }

    td:not(:first-child) {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><button class="button" id="B1">1</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button class="button" id="B2">2</button></td>
      <td align="center"><button class="button" id="B3">3</button></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table><br><br><br><br>
</body>

</html>
```